# Attr_accessor и subclass

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Есть модель User и у нее два подкласса Developer и Buyer (дочерние модели).
В каждой дочерней модели есть константа FIELDS.

В модели User:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor *:get_fields

  after_initialize :get_additional_fields

  # выбираю FIELDS для текущего класса
    def self.get_fields
      Object.const_get( self.name )::FIELDS
    end

  # устанавливаю изначальные значения
  # для дополнительных полей
  #
    def get_additional_fields
      self.country = 'text'
    end
end
```

Получаю ошибку `NoMethodError: undefined method`country=' for #<Developer:`

Подскажите, что не так?

Comment: Молю Аллаха, чтобы мне не пришлось поддерживать твой код, и вообще как-то взаимодействовать.

Answer (score 1):

Зачем тебе `SomeClass.get_fields`, если то же самое ты можешь получить с помощью `SomeClass::FIELDS`? Или это ты так решил поиграть в инкапсуляцию, типо "true" OOP?

```
attr_accessor *:get_fields
```

Что это вообще за синтаксическая конструкция? Если понаобъявлять полей, то почему не

```
attr_accessor *FIELDS
```

> `self.get_additional_fields`

Задаёшь поля, а метод назвал `get_`. Не по христу. А надо бы `set_`. Кроме того, непонятно зачем вообще нужен этот метод.

Answer (score 0):

```
def self.get_additional_fields
  country = 'text'
end
```

попробуй)

Comment: малаца, локальную переменную замутил пацанчик!